# I can't run my node application in my on prem VM

Tags: node.js, redhat, rhel7

I'm trying to run a node js application on an on-prem VM which is running RHEL 7. I'm not experienced in RHEL 7 and can't seem to find any details in running Node JS apps on it.

My app is super simple. Is a server which returns a message...

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Welcome Node.js');
}).listen(8000);
console.log('Server running on http://ip:8000');
```

I run the application and try accessing the IP with the port in the browser within the correct network. Am I missing something? My assumption was RHEL7 was the server and would show me the application once I open it on the browser.

Comment: We won't be able to help you here - it's a devops issue, make sure the port is open the firewall is configured to allow opening that port and accept incoming connections on it, the computers can find eachother on the network etc. It's not actually related to node.js - it'd be the exact same issue with any other server-side platform.

Comment: Hmm, that's why you should never assume about it being code and such :). Okay, I'll get the lads who worked on the VM to look at the firewall and such :)